# How to remove texlive 2009 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: uninstall, texlive

I installed texlive 2009 in my system by accident, and I have use every way I know to remove it. Did not work...

```
sudo apt-get remove texlive
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package texlive is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

but if type `tex` in the terminal...

```
tex 
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
```

Comment: **How** did you install it?

Comment: I installed it through Ubuntu Software Center. Remove it from the software center also did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
sudo apt-get purge texlive-*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I used autoremove before, but did not use autoclean. Now the problem has fixed!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: For my first attempt to uninstall I tried running `sudo apt purge texlive-*` (on 20.04), as I thought the commands `apt` and `apt-get` were identical in the current context. However, `apt` returns *"E: Unable to locate package texlive-\*"*, while `apt-get` runs the uninstall normally. Any idea why `apt-get` works and `apt` not?