# Removing Texlive From Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Installed using terminal, apt-get)

Tags: uninstall, latex, texlive, removing

I am using TexLive 2015 and I would like to move on to 2016 or even better 2017.
 I read on internet that uninstalling and doing a fresh install is a better idea than upgrading TexLive, is it true?
Anyways I started looking for the ways to see how I can uninsntall TexLive from my ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 bit) and I found this:
[Open the link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu/120286)
I had installed Texlive using terminal so the path is `\usr\share\texlive` and not `\usr\local\texlive` as suggested in the above link.
My question is to uninstall TexLive, is it necessary to go through all those steps?
If yes, the only change I need to make in those commands is changing the path from `\usr\local\texlive` to `\usr\share\texlive` or I should change something more?
Thanks

Comment: Which did you use to install it, `apt` or `apt-get` or `custom build` note all are via terminal!

Comment: Best option use `dpkg-query -L testlive` to determine the files to remove

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen , I used apt-get, how does that matter? asking out of curiosity.

Comment: It matters because the method of install determines the method of removal, now please run `whereis textlive` so we know what files will be removed and adapt that link answer

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen, here is the results for `whereis texlive`: `\usr\share\texlive`, as mentioned earlier. So now i just need to follow the instruction in the link using the path of my own?

Comment: It returns only one result, did you run `apt purge` previously?

Comment: not at all, what information exactly do you need? also when i run `dpkg -L texlive` it says that the package is not installed!!!

Comment: Ok work with that then!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well as it turns out, to do the job of removing TexLive, one simply needs to:

```
sudo apt-get purge texlive-*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

As suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485542/how-to-remove-texlive-2009-on-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1)
That's all!

Comment: That was enough to do a TinyTeX install without running into any errors, on Ubuntu 18.04. Cheers!

Comment: if you get an error, try `sudo apt-get purge "texlive-*"`